# How to make only part of a textField work like a hyperlink in a JasperReports document?

Tags: hyperlink, jasper-reports

Is there a way to put a hyperlink in a substring of a textField on a JasperReports document?  I know that an entire textField element can be made into a hyperlink, but I have a business requirement to have only a few words inside of a textField be a link.  It's a link to a website.

We're using *iReport 1.2.0* if that matters. (I know it's old, but I can't do anything about that.)

Comment: I think, no. But you can use several textFields instead of one

Comment: @AlexK, I thought about placing a textField with just the linked text over the original one, but the problem is the original one doesn't have a fixed location on the report.  Guaranteeing they always line up will be a nightmare (if possible at all), and even more so if any modifications are made to the report in the future.

Comment: You can also try a html markup with link

Comment: @AlexK, thanks.  I did, the report just ignored it.  I did have the styled text flag on and it did correctly handle a <u> tag elsewhere in the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else drops by with a similar issue, the solution I ended up going with was to just use separate textFields for the paragraph and for the linked text as discussed in the comments on the question.  It turned out to be much less tedious than I was expecting.  (But then we had other issues with the link playing nicely in a PDF embedded in a webpage, so we scrapped the links entirely.)